# C programming login system: finding a username

Tags: c

Ok, so basically i have to make a simple login system for a project, i have decided to use files for this and have a small log of random generic accounts here, along with their username and password.

```
Apple Password 
Banana abcdefg 
Vader Starwars 
Skywalker jedi
Chief Weapon 
Gravity Planet 
Lightyear long 
Hammer nail 
Hot-rod car 
Speed fast 
Shield cover 
Tech machine 
Pony My_little
Cat Alone
Bro Love
Banshee Ghast
```

Now I found some program online that will search for a string, and tell me which line it is on thus i can then find the password, however when i downloaded it and ran it, there were several problems:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//Just some function prototypes.
int Search_in_File(char *str, char *fname);
void Usage(char *filename);

//Our main function.
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int result, errno;

    if(argc < 3 || argc > 3) {
        Usage(argv[0]);
        //exit(1);
        getch();
    }

    //Use system("cls") on windows
    //Use system("clear") on Unix/Linux
    system("cls");

    result = Search_in_File(argv[1], argv[2]);
    if(result == -1) {
        perror("Error");
        printf("Error number = %d\n", errno);
        getch();
        //exit(1);
    }
    return(0);
}

void Usage(char *filename) {
    printf("fdhjx");
}

int Search_in_File(char *fname, char *str) {
    FILE *fp;
    int line_num = 1;
    int find_result = 0;
    char temp[512];

    //gcc users
    if((fp = fopen("Student Data base.txt", "r")) == NULL) 
        {
            return(-1);
        }

    /*Visual Studio users
      if((fopen_s(&fp, fname, "r")) != NULL) {
      return(-1); */
    //}
    while(fgets(temp, 512, fp) != NULL) {
        if((strstr(temp, str)) != NULL) {
            printf("A match found on line: %d\n", line_num);
            printf("\n%s\n", temp);
            find_result++;
        }
        line_num++;
    }

    if(find_result == 0) {
        printf("\nSorry, couldn't find a match.\n");
    }

    //Close the file if still open.
    if(fp) {
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return(0);
}


/* Bonus
   /* Below you'll find another way to handle
   /* files and error-handling using a stream. *\

   //FILE *stream = fopen("test.txt", "r");
   //if(!stream) {
   /* Handle error properly here */
//return;
//}
//fprintf(stream, "Hello world!");
//fclose(stream);
```

It compiles just fine, but the output just crashes and stops working, can anyone spot the problem?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Do you actually provide at least two command line arguments?

Comment: It does not seem to crash even funny place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling with warnings enabled tells me,

`warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getch’`

`getch` is apparently declared in the Console I/O header `conio.h`.  The `getch` is not part of the core functionality of your routine, so

1. commenting those out (as well as the `system("cls")` line that my Mac doesn't understand at runtime) and
2. providing both command-line args

gives a working routine:

```
./zpa fakefilename Sky
A match found on line: 4

Skywalker jedi
```

Note that the `fname` argument for `Search_in_File` isn't being used, so command-line input could be reduced to one argument.  Reducing borrowed code to the minimal core that you need is usually very helpful for debugging things.